# What is $\frac{\left(A \cap B\right)}{C}$ and $\frac{C}{\left(A \cap B\right)}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A=\{3,5,6,7,9\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4,7\}$ and $C=\{3,4,5,6\}$

I found the following:

$A\cap B=\{3,7\}$

$A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$

$\frac{\left(A\cap B\right)}{C}=\{1,\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{5},\frac{1}{3},\frac{7}{3},\frac{7}{4},\frac{7}{5},\frac{7}{6}\}$

Assuming this is correct, then I should be able to solve, $\frac{C}{\left(A \cap B\right)}$ the same way, right?

Comment: If $\frac XY$ is $\left\{\frac ab\,:\, a\in X\wedge b\in Y\right\}$, then yes.

Comment: Are you sure it's written $\dfrac{A \cap B}{C}$, and not $(A \cap B) \setminus C$?

Comment: (apart from the fact that, if it's as I said, it should be $\frac12$ instead of $\frac13$)

Comment: @M.Vinay it was written the second way, which is part of my confusion.

Comment: Then no: $X\setminus Y$ is the set of elements of $X$ which are *not* elements of $Y$.

Comment: @free_mind Then it's the [set difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html) operation. From the first set, remove any elements that be present in the second set. That is
$$A \setminus B = \{a \in A \mid a \not\in B \}.$$ Also denoted by $A - B$. It is, in other words, the complement of $B$ *with respect to* $A$.

Comment: @M.Vinay interesting because I understand the notation $A-B$ but didn't know it was the same as $A$ \ $B$.  Thanks for that clarification

Comment: @free_mind And this is not to be confused with the [symmetric difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricDifference.html) (which is more like the XOR of logic)!

Comment: It is worth mentioning that there is similar notation for unrelated concepts as well:  $A/\sim$ for a set $A$ and an equivalence relation (on $A$), $\sim$, would refer to the set of equivalence classes of $\sim$.  Related, $G/H$ where $G$ is a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ is the quotient group (or factor group), which is the group of cosets of $H$.  The first may come up when you study relations (as a convenient way of defining $\Bbb Z_n$) and the second will come up once you start studying group theory.  Don't confuse $G/H$ and $G\setminus H$.